# Pre-sorting associations in controller: How and is there a performance gain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a view which loops through `@regions`. For each region its countries are displayed.

```
<% region.countries.each do |country| %>
```

A new requirement is to sort the countries by some column, which I have a scope for.

```
<% region.countries.order_alphabetically.each do |country| %>
```

However I heard that writing logic in views will severely impact the performance. Is it true for this case? Is is possible to pre-sort this in the controller?

P.S. I don't want to use default_scope because I need to sort it differently in other views.

EDIT: changed title to better reflect my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer. I wanted to see some evidence, so I finally make time to sit down and write a benchmarking comparison of the two: [sorting in view and controller demo](https://github.com/lulalala/benchmark).

In the page there are many regions, each regions have many countries. The page display all of them, sorting countries by name for each of the region. Run `rake test:benchmark` and the results will be saved in tmp/performance folder. The results of the two are the same, at around 0.0035 per page render.

So in summary, calling a sorting scope in view VS in controller makes no difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's faster likely depends on how many records you have in your table and whether you're indexing on that column. You can experiment with passing this load of onto the database by doing:

```
region.countries.order(:column_name)
```

This should be faster in most cases than loading all the records into Ruby and sorting.

Comment: Thanks. What I meant to say though is whether I should/can place the query condition in the controller instead of view. I won't be sorting the query results in ruby for sure.

Comment: There's no performance difference between the controller and the view. The same code needs to execute regardless of where it is.

Answer (score 0):

What would be undesirable would be if, in 3 different places in your view you put

```
region.countries.order(:column_name)
```

This would hit the database 3 times. Some would also argue that you're making the view do too much. You could address both concerns by doing

```
@sorted_countries = region.countries.order(:column_name)
```

You're keeping the specifics of how to order out of the view and by reusing the same relation active record will cache the sorted array between reuses.

If you're only using the sorted countries in one place then there shouldn't be any difference, although splitting it out like this makes it a maybe little easier to write a spec that tests that the countries are being sorted and makes it less likely you'll accidentally end up in the performance pitfall detailed above

Comment: yeah the problem is there are multiple regions. I can have an array of this but would not to if there is no performance impact